# javascript setInterval not repeating in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function get_stock_data(symbol, index) {
    var url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22"+ symbol +"%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=";
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        var price = $(".stock-price");
        price[index].innerHTML = "";
        price[index].appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.query.results.quote.Change));
        console.log(data);
    }).success(function() {
        console.log("success");
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log("Failed");
    }); 
}


$("document").ready(function() {

    var symbol = $(".stock-symbol");

    for(var i = 0; i < symbol.length; i++) {
        setInterval(get_stock_data(symbol[i].firstChild.textContent, i) , 1000);
        console.log("hello");
    }
});
```

The problem in this script is that get_stock_data function executes only once...plz help...i want the data to be updated to DOM..

Comment: Have you checked the inspector? Has it returned any errors?

Comment: There is a problem with your architecture, you are trying to do asynchronous things in synchronous way, and besides wrong call of setInterval. Your loop must to be overwritten at all

Comment: The first argument to setInterval should be a function.

Comment: you executing function inside `setInterval` instead of passing reference to it, which `setInterval` will execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
function get_stock_data(symbol, index) {
    var url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22" + symbol + "%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=";
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        var price = $(".stock-price");
        price[index].innerHTML = "";
        price[index].appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.query.results.quote.Change));
        console.log(data);
    }).success(function () {
        console.log("success");
    }).fail(function () {
        console.log("Failed");
    });
}
function setUpInterval() {
    var symbol = $(".stock-symbol");
    for (var i = 0; i < symbol.length; i++) {
        setInterval("get_stock_data(" + symbol[i] + "," + i + ")", 1000);
    }
}
setUpInterval();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `get_stock_data` in your `setInterval` call. So it gets called once and only once. You are actually passing `undefined` to `setInterval`, because `get_stock_data` doesn't return anything.

The first argument of `setInterval` should be the function you want to call. In this case, it looks like you want to call get_stock_data with some passed-in parameters. To make this work with `setInterval`, you'll need to pass in an anonymous function like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < symbol.length; i++) {
  setInterval(function() { get_stock_data(symbol[i].firstChild.textContent, i); }, 1000);
}
```

This way you are passing in the *function* to `setInterval`, which `setInterval` will call every 1000 (or so) milliseconds.